# Is it possible to start grails server application in junit

Tags: grails, junit

I have a grails application and I'm writing testcases in junit. is there any way to start grails server using JUNIT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run your unit test by --

**Run as JUnit Test**

or otherwise

**test-app: Runs all Grails unit and integration tests and generates reports.**

In your case you could do:

**test-app unit:**

or

**test-app integration:**

or for a specific ExampleTests.groovy file:

**test-app unit: Example**

Comment: Thanks, that means test-app itself start the server? no need to write separate junit code to start the application(server).